# GHC compilation bug?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Some time ago I devised a little system to make compilation and testing of my Haskell programs a bit more comfortable. My project root looks as follows:

```
./bin/
./bin/myMain
./bin/test
./interfaces/
./obj/
./src/
./src/makefile
./src/MyLib.hs
./src/myMain.hs
./src/testSuite.hs
```

*myMain* is the main module, whose imports are like those:

```
import MyLib
-- irrelevant content follows
```

*testSuite* is similar:

```
import System.Exit
import Test.HUnit
import MyLib
-- irrelevant content follows
```

I compile those with two simple commands:

```
ghc  testSuite.hs -o ../bin/test -odir ../obj -hidir ../interfaces
ghc  myMain.hs -o ../bin/myMain -odir ../obj -hidir ../interfaces
```

Now, as I run the first, whole test suite compiles and executes perfectly fine, even if there are any object or intereface files present. However when I run the second to compile main executable, it compiles test binary again unless I run remove object and interface files.

The reason is, as far as I found, that main module produces `Main.o` and `Main.hi`, no matter what its name is. Therefore while compiling myMain, GHC sees those files present, so does not recompile main module. The strange part is this is not the case when I compile test suite - in such a case Main is recompiled even if there are objects and interfaces present.

```
$ ghc  testSuite.hs -o ../bin/test -odir ../obj -hidir ../interfaces
[1 of 2] Compiling MyLib       ( MyLib.hs, ../obj/MyLib.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main        ( testSuite.hs, ../obj/Main.o )
Linking ../bin/test ...

$ ghc  myMain.hs -o ../bin/myMain -odir ../obj -hidir ../interfaces
Linking ../bin/myMain ...
```

But when I run main compilation first:

```
$ ghc  myMain.hs -o ../bin/myMain -odir ../obj -hidir ../interfaces
[1 of 2] Compiling MyLib       ( MyLib.hs, ../obj/MyLib.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main        ( myMain.hs, ../obj/Main.o )
Linking ../bin/myMain ...

$ ghc  testSuite.hs -o ../bin/test -odir ../obj -hidir ../interfaces
[2 of 2] Compiling Main        ( testSuite.hs, ../obj/Main.o ) [Test.HUnit changed]
Linking ../bin/test ...
```

What's even stranger, the problem disappears when I put aside `-odir` and `-hidir` GHC parameters and compile everything in the same directory. Why?

[NOTE:]

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3
```

Comment: Which version of GHC are you using?

Comment: GHC 7.6.3 right away from Debian Jessie package repository

Comment: Is there any reason not to use cabal?

Comment: Only that I didn't think I really need it for such a simple project. Do I?